# Updating column on one table with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update an empty table notes, with values that come from a column in another table deals:

```
UPDATE notes
SET notes.content = (
SELECT deals.memo
FROM deals
WHERE deals.id = notes.deal_id
);
```

this runs with no error but no notes get updated although there are loads of values in memo.

There's no values at all in notes. Can this be the problem?

Comment: If there are no records in notes table, then yes, that is why nothing is updated. There's nothing to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to *insert* rows into `notes`:

```
INSERT INTO notes (deal_id, content)
    SELECT d.id, d.ememo
    FROM deals;
```

This will add rows into `notes` with values from the rows in `deals`.

Comment: Perfect, that made it. Thank you